# Exception Handling while making Multiple copies of a file in different folders

Tags: java

I'm copying a file to multiple folders, say I have an `abc.htm` which needs to be copied in `c:/test1`, `c:/test2` .... `c:/test10` using Java program. I need to make sure that the copying is successfull either in all the 10 folders or the if it fails in between file should be deleted from all the folders.
Every time I make the copy I'm returning the path, now I'm seeking help on setting the retry count for copying and even if the retry fails all the copies of `abc.htm` should be deleted from folders to which it was copied.
Can any one provide any pointers on the same.

Comment: If the file is already there and you overwrite it do you still want to delete the original?

Answer (score 1):

Do an error check after you finish writing all of the files. Write them like:

```
Write file 1;
flush stream;
Write file 2;
flush stream;
...
...
write file 10;
flush stream;
```

Store all of your paths in an array as Strings and do something like :

```
for (int i=0; i<paths.length; i++)
    if (!(new File(paths[i]).exists()))
        for (int j=0; j<paths.length; j++)
            new File(paths[j]).delete();
```

Haven't used java in a while, but the `exists()` will definitely check the existence of a file, and if there is no file method `destroy()` then you can always do

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm " + paths[j]);`

Checking like this will results in the removal of all files in the case that one of them does not exist. Hope this helps.

--edit

Cowls is right, you really should start accepting answers. No one is going to answer your questions.

Comment: Hi Jay,Thanks for the pointers,what i 'm trying to do is executing copy one by one and checking the file path value of the file created.If that's null i need to execute another loop for retrying the copy and if that even fails ,i need to delete all the files copied.